# C++ Error: no matching function for call - when used in class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, unordered-map

I am trying to create a class that holds three unordered maps. Initialised like so:

```
public:
std::unordered_map<int,int> umap;
std::unordered_map<int,sf::VertexArray> tilemap;
std::unordered_map<int,Hex> hmap;
```

The first two aren't that important right now, my issue is with the third (hmap), which should hopefully be built in the constructor.

The structure Hex, which is the type of the map, looks like this:

```
struct Hex { // Cube storage, cube constructor
    int q, r, s;                                     //integers q, r and s define the grid location relative to center
    Hex(int q_, int r_, int s_): q(q_), r(r_), s(s_) {
        if (q + r + s != 0) throw "q + r + s must be 0";
    }
};
```

which for interest, isn't my code, it came from here:
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html
but I did change the int's q,r,s from being constants, in case this is important. This was done to overcome some other error that I kept getting.

the other mathematical functions I am using from this repository are:

```
//adds the q, r and s components of two hexagons a and b together.
Hex hex_add(Hex a, Hex b) {
    return Hex(a.q + b.q, a.r + b.r, a.s + b.s);
}

//multiplies the q, r and s components of one hexagon by a scalar, k is a scaling factor
Hex hex_multiply(Hex a, int k) {
    return Hex(a.q * k, a.r * k, a.s * k);
}
```

So the constructor currently looks like this:

```
game_map(int rings, int width, int height, bool hexagonalif){

    //store all inputs in pre-determined private variables
    ishexagonal = hexagonalif;
    w = width;
    ring = rings;
    h = height;

    int counter =0;
    if(ishexagonal==true){
        //hexagonal map option
        for (int q = -ring; q <= ring; q++) {
            int r1 = std::max(-ring, -q - ring);
            int r2 = std::min(ring, -q + ring);
            for (int r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
          //          Hex NOW = Hex(q, r, -q-r);
          //      hmap[counter]=(NOW);
          //      counter++;
            }
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<h;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<=w;j++){

                Hex hexag1 = hex_add(hex_multiply(hex_direction(5), i), hex_multiply(hex_direction(0), j));
              //  Hex hexag =Hex(hexag1.q,hexag1.r,hexag1.s);
                hmap[counter]= hexag1;//
                counter ++;

            }
        }
    }
    countmax = counter;
}
```

The error I am getting is a common 'no matching function for call to Hex::Hex()', on line `hmap[counter]=hexag1;` which I understand is usually because I am trying to create a Hex without giving its constructor the necessary arguments (q,r,s in this case).

I really don't understand this. The hexagon is being correctly made in the line before. I am then trying to store it in its correct place on the unordered map. This method of creation and then storing in an unordered map I have used before and worked fine, for other types of data (including the sf::VertexArray I initialise) whilst it was in a seperate function, but putting it into the class seems to have stopped it. I have tried every concievable quick fix or alternate method of putting it into the unordered map that I could think of.

The other thing that I also noticed is that my usual method of initialising Hex doesn't work when it is being done within the class. I have no idea why this is, but it doesn't really matter as I can get round it. I have put what works and what usually works (in comments) below:

```
Hex h = Hex(0,0,0);
//  Hex h(0,0,0);
```

Please could anyone explain what is the error here getting upset about? How can I get round it? Also, I am well aware that my understanding of all of this is rudimentary. If anyone has the time to fill me in on why half of this stuff is a problem, or any other useful background, then that would be extremely useful.

But not essential.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this!

Comment: `hmap.emplace(counter, hexag1);` should work. I'm sure this has a dupe though

Comment: Simply making the access `hmap[counter]` default-constructs a `Hex` object in order to return a reference to it. Simplest way out is adding a default constructor.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `map_name[some_value]` is both a "setter" and a "getter".  In order to be a getter, there needs to already be an object there.

Comment: "I did change the ints q,r,s from being constants" - I hope this hasn't broken invariants the existing library counted on to behave properly!